# Accidentally used rasa run command

Tags: server, rasa

I just installed rasa in a virtual environment using venv

I used rasa run instead of rasa shell

The docs site says this "starts a server"... what does that mean?

What files did this generate and is there a server operating in the background now?

Answer (score 2):

`rasa run` starts a server which serves your chatbot model via your selected  [channel connector](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/). You could for example let your users talk to the chatbot via Facebook messenger, Twilio or some website. If you run `rasa run --enable-api` it in addition activates a couple of [API endpoints](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/http-api) which allow you to interact with the conversation histories and the model.

When you cancel the command (e.g. via `STRG+C` or closing the terminal window), the server will be stopped. Nothing will be left running in the background.

Fun fact: `rasa shell` is actually using `rasa run` under the hood. Your command line input will be sent as an HTTP request to the Rasa server and the server's response will be printed to the command line.

Comment: Hey Tobias, your response was very helpful!